# Typing writing with js and html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't figure it out how to make this text `responsive`.
when the text is too long, it went off the screen from right side. and I can't get it to auto break line. Here is the link for [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtqhmmjL/2/)

Comment: Hi.  Can you set a maximum width to the .cd-words-wrapper class?

Comment: Hi, please edit the code into your question body, rather than writing your link as a code snippet to bypass the code restriction.

Comment: @Serlite  you want me to put source code here? if so , there is too many code involved css, html and js.

Comment: @YakyRefael I try that but still not working!

Comment: @Madeny Ideally, you would want to put a [mcve] in your question body, which may not encompass all your code - just enough to reproduce the problem. The reason why there's a requirement you put code in your question (which you bypassed by making the link into a code snippet) is because external links have the potential to break in the future, which would make your post useless to learn from for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Please make use of `vw` which will give you responsive fonts as per you need it.

All you need is simple change in your forn size.

```
.cd-headline {
    font-size: 4.4vw;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
```

I have made changes in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtqhmmjL/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Please remove from : .cd-headline.clip the whitespace: no-wrap.

```
.cd-words-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 white-space: normal;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks any way but that breaks my text.